# Difference between feature_importances_ and feature_importance() in lightgbm

Tags: lightgbm

There are two types of feature importance in LightGBM, namely feature_importance() for lightgbm.Booster and feature_importances_ for lightgbm.LGBMClassifier. feature_importance() contains two types of feature importance, "split" and "gain". My main question is: which one is used for feature_importances_ for Scikit-learn API? "split", "gain" or "mean decrease in impurity" as defaulted in scikit-learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `.feature_importances_` property on a fitted `lightgbm.sklearn` estimator uses the `"split"` importance type.

As described in LightGBM's docs ([link](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html)), the estimators from `lightgbm.sklearn` take a keyword argument `importance_type` which controls what type of importance is returned by the `feature_importances_` property.

> **importance_type (str, optional (default='split')).**
>
> *The type of feature importance to be filled into feature_importances_. If ‘split’, result contains numbers of times the feature is used in a model. If ‘gain’, result contains total gains of splits which use the feature.*

Here's an example using `lightgbm==4.1.0` and Python 3.11.

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

# generate data
X, y = make_blobs(
    n_samples=1_000,
    n_features=4,
    centers=2
)

# train a model
clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier(
    n_estimators=10,
).fit(X,y)

# .feature_importances defaults to "split"
clf.feature_importances_
# array([21,  1,  4,  0], dtype=int32)

# if you set importance_type to "gain", it'll be the
# cumulative gain from all splits involving that feature
clf.importance_type = "gain"
clf.feature_importances_
# array([5.21306300e+03, 3.55271008e-15, 1.27897657e-13, 0.00000000e+00])
```